# Get earlier value using DAX Measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

**Objective:** I would like to turn a calculated column formula into a measure since the `EARLIER` function isn't possible for measures.

**Query to modify:**

```
VAR sumed_exp = 
    DIVIDE(
        SUM(Retention[Week n-1]),
        SUM(Retention[Week n-2])
        )
VAR PrevDay =
    CALCULATE (
        LASTDATE ( Retention[Report Date] ),
        Retention[Report Date] < EARLIER ( Retention[Report Date] )
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    sumed_exp,
    PrevDay 
    )
```

**Explanation:**
Basically I want the last value where the value expressed is:

- `sum` of all values in column Week n-1 `divided` by
- `sum` of all values in column Week n-2

Comment: If you want to use `sumed_exp` inside a `CALCULATE` to modify its filter context, you need to make it a measure instead of a constant variable. `CALCULATE` won't change a constant.

Comment: it works now by making it a measure... i didn't know it made a difference

Comment: A measure is a bit like a function. It will evaluate differently in different contexts. A variable is a constant once you've defined it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a standard [DAX Pattern for a cumulative total](https://www.daxpatterns.com/cumulative-total/).

You use `MAX` instead of `EARLIER` inside a `FILTER`.

```
VAR PrevDay =
    CALCULATE (
        LASTDATE ( Retention[Report Date] ),
        FILTER (
            ALL ( Retention[Report Date] ),
            Retention[Report Date] < MAX ( Retention[Report Date] )
        )
    )

RETURN
CALCULATE(
    DIVIDE(
        SUM(Retention[Week n-1]),
        SUM(Retention[Week n-2])
    ),
    Retention[Report Date] = PrevDay 
)
```

Note that this is a max in your current filter context not over the whole column.

Comment: I get the error message: "True/false expression does not specify a column..."

Comment: That's probably from your `CALCULATE` part. You can't just put a constant as a filter. Try putting `Retention[Report Date] = PrevDay` instead of just `PrevDay`.